# java mail - use dynamic sender email address

Tags: spring, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using email services (with my custom domain) from google. I want to use dynamic sender email address i.e. When user registers he should receive email from register@example.com and when he place order, should receive email from orders@example.com

I have used java mail to send emails and application is developed using spring framework. Emails are sent, only issue they are always received from username specified in spring configuration xml.

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(order.getCustomer().getEmailAddress()));
                mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@mycompany.com"));
                mimeMessage.setText(
                        "Dear " + order.getCustomer().getFirstName() + " "
                            + order.getCustomer().getLastName()
                            + ", thank you for placing order. Your order number is "
                            + order.getOrderNumber());
            }
        };
```

Any idea, where I am going wrong ?

Comment: you need to share code

Comment: I have updated my question with code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed the [Gmail instructions for sending from a different email address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)?

Comment: Thanks, I am able to send email from desired address.Now issue is sent emails does not reflect in account from which email is sent.

Comment: If you login as X and send as Y, is the sent message saved in the X account?  If so, and that's not what you want, you'll need to login as Y and send as Y.

Comment: Yes, Sent as Y saved in X account. So you mean I need to alter properties of mailsender bean (username and password)?

Comment: Yes, you need to login as Y instead of X.  If you login as Y and send as Y, it will be saved in Y's account.

Comment: Thanks will check this.